# Cannot get the the GET parameters on the URL with Laravel when the Url is not the root one

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I'm using the following `Laravel` version:

```
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.5.44
```

On my `Laravel` routes I have the following:

```
...
Route::get('/', function () {
    myLog(Input::all());
});

Route::get('/name', function () {
    myLog(Input::all());
});
...
```

When I go to the following url (first route):

https://my.website.com/?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3

I get on the logs file:

```
2019-03-11 16:15:17|DEBUG|{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3"}
```

which is fine.

**My problem is** when I go to the following url (second route):

https://my.website.com/name?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3

(notice: `/name`)

I get on the logs file:

```
2019-03-11 16:15:45|DEBUG|{"url":"name"}
```

Any idea about why when I use a `Laravel` route other than the root one, I cannot get the parameters on the url passed in a `Get` way?

I need to retrieve those parameters only as a `Get`, that's a requirement for me.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What server are you using at `my.website.com`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue on my case.

For some reason I was using the following `Rewrite Rule` on the `.htaccess`. Pay attention to that file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Hope that helps somebody.